# Get all Related Products which are not available in Related Product Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say i have Product and RelatedProduct tables,

```
Product
------
ID
Name

RelatedProduct
--------------
ID
ProductID
RelatedProductID
RelatedProductName
```

Now I a @ProductID parameter. I need to get all products which are not already added in RelatedProduct table. So, if I have

```
Product
-----------
ID     Name
 1      A1
 2      A2
 3      A3
 4      A4


RelatedProduct
-----------------------------------------
ID     Name   ProductID    RelatedProductID
 1      B1       2             1
 2      B2       4             3
 3      B3       2             4
```

If @ProductID =1, then I need Product's 2,3,4. If @ProductID = 2, then I need Product's 3. If @ProductID = 4, then I need Product's 1,2.

Comment: how are the tables related with each other?

Comment: @JW, simply RelatedProduct.ProductID and RelatedProduct.RelatedProductID always belong to Product.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from    Product
where   id not in
  (select RelatedProductID
   from   RelatedProduct
   where  productID = @productID)
```

NOTE: if product 1 is related to product 2, is product 2 then also related to product 1? Your examples explicitly say no, but often this kind of relationship is bi-directional.

Comment: I am testing thanks, but I think you are missing union select @productID